# A Frame VR Headset / Browser Compatibility

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, headset

Does anyone know of a cheap alternative to Oculus Rift / Vive that has controls and is browser / A-Frame compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Oculus Rift, HTC Vive and WMR headsets are all valid options for desktop. 
And you're not stuck with Edge if you want WMR - you can use Windows MR headsets as SteamVR devices via an official Microsoft SteamVR plugin (but Edge with Windows Mixed Reality is quite good, really).

You did not specify if you want 6DOF. If 3DOF is enough, there's also mobile - GearVR works very well and has a controller, Daydream isn't that bad too. If you're really desperate there's also cardboard with which you can use a bluetooth gamepad or something.

I'm maintaining [360WebPlayer](https://github.com/BIVROST/360WebPlayer/#supported-browsers) and I have an up to date list of supported browser/device combinations. It's not using A-Frame, but the list should be close.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, on Desktop the only headsets that browsers support are Oculus Rift and HTC Vive on Firefox / Chrome / Supermedium and Windows Mixed Reality headsets on Microsoft Edge.

Mobile headsets only support a single 3DOF controller at the moment. Your options are Samsung Internet and Oculus Browser for Gear VR and Oculus Go and Chrome for Daydream headsets.

Check [Web VR Rocks](https://webvr.rocks/) periodically for an up to date compatibility table.